# Powershell execute file with path in parameters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run SqlPackage.exe from Powershell using a variable string as SourceFile parameter:

```
$fileExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe"

& $fileExe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:$OutputVariable\file.dacpac /Profile:C:\sql\file.sqldatabase.publish.xml
```

Where $OutputVariable is the folder containing the full path

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
SqlPackage.exe : *** Illegal characters in path.
At C:\powershell\test.ps1:20 char:6
+      & $fileExe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:$OutputVariable\file.dacpac     /Profile:C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (*** Illegal characters in path.:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I tried surrounding with quotes and splitting the parameters but I did not get to a solution.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is an example value of $OutputVariable?

Comment: C:\temp\build\DB1
OR
C:\temp\build\DB2
etc

Comment: Try replacing it with the actual string just to see if it works, that would at least confirm the problem is specifically with that variable.

Comment: Yes I already tried and it actually works

Comment: Can you `test-path` `$OutputVariable\file.dacpac`? What if you `Join-Path $OutputVariable file.dacpac`?

Comment: The test-path actually fails:
this is the output of the variable $OutputVariable
C:\temp\DB_Name\DB_NameDB_20150410.18
and this is the test-path output:
test-path : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\temp\test.ps1:27 char:6
+      test-path $OutputVariable
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\temp\DB...B_20150410.18
:String) [Test-Path], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
 
False

Comment: What happens when you try this `Test-Path $OutputVariable.Trim()`. I feel that there is some white-space on the end or something you cant see.

Comment: Yes! I just figured it out that by trimming it, it works. And you just gave me the confirmation, thanks for that!
That's crazy tho...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently by trimming the $OutputVariable

```
$OutputVariable.Trim()
```

The problem is fixed.

Comment: Which indicates that OutputVariable had a space at the start or end which would indeed trigger that error as file names cannot start with a space.